# InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I asked this question 6 years ago. In the meantime Android development best practices have changed, and I have become a better developer.

Since then, I have realized that using the `onClick` XML attribute is a bad practice, and have removed it from any code base I work on.

All of my click handlers are now defined in the code of the app, not the XML layouts!

My reasons for never using `onClick` are

1. it is easy to make a mistake in the value of the `onClick` XML attribute, which will then result in a run-time error
2. a developer might refactor the name of the click handler method, without realizing it is called from a layout (see reason 1)
3. finding out which method is actually being called is not always obvious. Especially if the layout is being used by a Fragment
4. separating the concerns of layout vs behavior is good. Using `onClick` mixes them up, which is bad!

I hope I have convinced you to never use `onClick` in a layout :) !

Below is my original question, which is a pretty good illustration of why using `onClick` is a bad idea.

===

I'm defining menu items in XML, and trying to use the onClick attribute that was added in API 11. When the Activity is launched in an emulator running 4.0.3, the following Exceptions occur:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler 
    onFeedbackMenu in class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper

...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onFeedbackMenu 
    [interface com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
```

I don't understand what is causing the Exception, since the following method is defined in my Activity

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
...
public void onFeedbackMenu( MenuItem menuItem ) { 
    Toast.makeText( this, "onFeedBack", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
```

My XML menu definition file contains:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_feedback"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/menu_feedback"
        android:onClick="onFeedbackMenu" />
</menu>
```

For backwards compatibility I am using ActionBarSherlock, and also getting a very similar Exception when I run the App on 2.3.x.

This is a more Complete version of the Stack trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler 
    onFeedbackMenu in class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:204)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:410)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:445)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:175)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:97)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onFeedbackMenu 
    [interface com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:202)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it seems to be related to applying a custom theme to ActionBarSherlock, though not sure... Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a custom theme.

Comment: Yeah this happens for me on a real 4.0.3 device, but not in the 4.1 emulator. I can only assume it is a bug in Android that has since been fixed. I'm not using ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: There are some excellent answers below. It would be a nice thing to do to accept an answer!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.
Usually the `onClick` attribute in a layout has the following method

```
public void methodname(View view) { 
    // actions
}
```

On a menu item (in this case Sherlock menu) it should follow the following signature:

```
public boolean methodname(MenuItem item) { 
    // actions
}
```

So, your problem was that your method returned `void` and not `boolean`.

Answer (score 16):

In my case, the `AndroidManifest.xml` of my application (kick-started by the default Eclipse assistant) contained `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in the `<application>` block.

When debugging the cause of the problem, it turned out that the line

```
mMethod = c.getMethod(methodName, PARAM_TYPES);
```

in `android.view.MenuInflater/InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener` was called with `c` not being my `Activity` class but a dubious `android.view.ContextThemeWrapper` (which of course doesn't contain the onClick handler).

So, I removed the `android:theme` and everything worked.

Comment: This one is interesting as it looks like this was the cause of my problem. However, anyone who needs (or wants) the theme set would end up with this issue (on API 14/15, not API 16+ from what I can tell). Thus, my solution was to drop the onClick assignment and just add calls to the onOptionsItemSelected() method.

Answer (score 9):

Although this is a bit out of date, here is the reason for the exception. When you look into the sources of android API 15 (4.0.3-4.0.4) in the class MenuInflater you will see this method:

```
public InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener(Context context, String methodName) {
mContext = context;
Class<?> c = context.getClass();
try {
    mMethod = c.getMethod(methodName, PARAM_TYPES);
} catch (Exception e) {
    InflateException ex = new InflateException(
            "Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler " + methodName +
            " in class " + c.getName());
    ex.initCause(e);
    throw ex;
}
```

This is were the exception happens, as Junique already pointed out. However the removing of the app theme is just a workaround and no real option. As we see the method tries to find the Callback method on the class of the context item passed. So instead of calling `getMenuInflater()` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` you should call `new MenuInflater(this)`, so that `this` is passed as a context and then the code will work.

You can still use `getMenuInflater()` for other api versions if you just use an if statement like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
        inflater = getMenuInflater();
    else
        inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
```

I don't actually know if the bug happens in api versions under 15 too, so i just generally used the save version.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I had **both** `onClick` in my menu XML and an `onCreateOptionsMenu` in my Activity. My `onClick` was actually faulty (because it pointed to non-existent methods) but I didn't notice this at first because I was testing under Android 2.x, where `onClick` is not supported and ignored. Once I tested on 4.x though, I started getting this error.

So basically, don't use `onClick` if you plan on deploying under Android 2.x. It will silently ignore your `onClick` values until you try running on 3.0+.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had the same problem with the ActionBar menu items, and their onClick events.  What i discovered is that the workstation I'm developing in had run out of memory and needed to be rebooted.  The Android VM is now able to resolve the method name referenced.

Comment: Update, when I rebooted, I didn't realize that the Android VM that came up was 2.3.3.  However, when I specifically selected that the Android VM be 4.0.3 I continued to get the error for onClick.

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_open);
        
        if (item == null)
         return true;
        
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener
        (
      new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener () 
      { 
          public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) 
       { return (showDirectory(item)); }
      } 
        ); 

        return true;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your method must accept a MenuItem as its only parameter per [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource).

```
    public void onMenuItemClickMethod(MenuItem menuItem){
        // Do stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_open);

    if (item == null)
        return true;

    item.setOnMenuItemClickListener
    (
        new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener () 
        { 
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) 
            { return (showDirectory(item)); }
        } 
    ); 

    return true;
}


public boolean showDirectory (MenuItem item)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: based on this thread .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150080/set-a-menu-item-as-checked-from-code .. it is suggested that programmers update menus using menu.findItem () vs findItemById().  To accomplish this, the menu option is maintained in either the onCreateOptionsMenu or onPrepareOptionsMenu .. discussed here .. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: The other thing that I think is happening with the XML file is that the onClick field can't resolve to a method matching the proper criteria ... it should be either ... public void [eventName] (MenuItem item) {} or public boolean [eventName] (MenuItem item) {}.  Neither though seem to work.